# Best way to split key:value pair into two pairs in a dictionary - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, split, key

So let's say i have a dictionary as:

```
d={'a-b':[1,2,3],'c-d':[4,5,6]}
```

And i want to split the keys, i.e `'a-b'` into two keys as `'a'` and `'b'`, and keep same value for both etc...

So desired output should be:

```
{'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [1, 2, 3], 'c': [4, 5, 6], 'd': [4, 5, 6]}
```

I know i can do (Thanks to @Netwave):

```
d={'a-b':[1,2,3],'c-d':[4,5,6]}
newd={}
for k,v in d.items():
    x,y=k.split('-')
    newd[x]=v
    newd[y]=v
print(newd)
#{'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [1, 2, 3], 'c': [4, 5, 6], 'd': [4, 5, 6]}
```

But i don't think that's efficient,

So i am hoping one of you can give a better solution.

Comment: Efficient according to... ? You are doing the bare minimum here so what are you hoping for?

Comment: @Julien Am... i am hoping for a shorter, more efficient way of doing this, like maybe in a dictionary comprehension or something...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `split` once:

```
for k,v in d.items():
    x, y = k.split("-")
    newd[x] = v
    newd[y] = v
```

Or iterate through it:

```
for k,v in d.items():
    for new_k in k.split("-")
        newd[new_k] = v
```

As a dict comprehension:

```
{new_k : v for k,v in d.items() for new_k in k.split("-")}
```